# after merging pull request in bit bucket I want to sync with local but getting message already up to date

Tags: git, bitbucket

I merged a pull request in bit bucket from a feature branch into master and now I want to update my local copy of master.  I've tried git fetch, git pull, git reset --hard, git reset --hard origin/master.  I was expecting my local master branch to be updated with the new commits, but it was not.  I am getting the message already up to date, and no changes are applied to my local copy. Any suggestions are appreciated.

--update

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    application/config/audio/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
--
git pull
Already up to date
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `git status`, then the exact sequence of commands you're running along with the output of those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found my problem.  I had forked the project from another and the updates were applied to the original project.  Of course they wouldn't show up as changes in the forked project until it is sync'd.  I guess the take away is make sure you are pointed to the repo that has your changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the master branch first. You can do this with git checkout master. Then you can pull the changes with git pull.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I am on master on my local copy.  git checkout master returns  "On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Comment: What worked for me was re-initializing the git repo in the project folder. I had to delete the .git folder and then re-run git init. Then I was able to commit and push. Obviously I had to recreate the remote & add the files but that should be easy.